# Webfleet .connect API not available for Webfleet LITE subscriptions?

Tags: api, tomtom

is that true? Webfleet .connect API is not available for Webfleet Lite subscriptions?

BR, Rene

Comment: why tomtom tag?

Comment: Webfleet was previously owned by TomTom. Some years ago Webfleet was acquired by Bridgestone. I added the tag "Tomtom" because maybe people will then respond with an answer as they might recognize they have been working with Webfleet .connect API in the past while it was still owned by TomTom. Do you have an answer on the question? Or why are you asking?